# Slow Emulator, no common suggestions work

Tags: android, graphics, windows-10, hardware-acceleration, bluestacks

So I have this interesting case where I have tried 3 different emulators on my PC:

Bluestacks, Nox and Memu

All of them are so much laggy. Nox works a bit better but you can't really play a game with it, still slow.

This is what I have tried so far:

1. Enabled virtualization. LeMoon says everything is alright
2. Updated the drivers for my graphics card and chipset (and almost everything else)
3. allocated 2 cores of CPU and 2048 MB ram to Nox

Nothing worked.

**PC Specs:**

- HP Core i3 with Windows 10 (64 bit)
- RAM - 4 GB DDR4
- CPU Type - Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz
- Intel SSD

**Graphics Chipset**

- AMD Radeon(TM) R5 M430
- Memory Size - 2048 MB
- Memory Type - DDR3
- Memory Clock - 1000 MHz
- Core Clock - 1030 MHz
- Total Memory Bandwidth - 16 GByte/s

Now, the same Nox setup works flawlessly on my secondary laptop which is just a second generation Core i5 with 4GB DDR3 RAM and a regular Hard drive instead of an SSD but running on 64 bit windows 7 (with VT enabled).

Any ideas?

Can windows 10 have an impact?

Comment: You need to Increase your Ram to 8 GB if you are using Android Studio In Windows 10 or else change to Windows 7 for Better Performance... There is No Tip . But Upgrade Your Hardware like Ram Boosts android Studio And Emulator Performance

Answer (score 0):

You do not have enough configuration on your PC and you want emulators to work properly?

For Android Studio and Emulators to work properly in Windows machine, you at least need 8GB of RAM with a 2GB Graphic Card.

Try upgrading the configs of your system and it will become better.

My Mac has only 2GB of Ram and it works like a charm. So reconsider.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Like I said in my question, the same emulator works flawlessly in a pc with an older processor and same amount of ram (but older DDR3)
It isn't the hardware.